# Android: How to Play song when listview item is selected

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-music-player

I have create one listview to play media file mp3 songs. If i am select 1st song to play,it is playing but if i select second or another song on listview then it play again 1st song. I want that if i select second or any other listview song they will be select to play.Kindly help me solve such issue...Thank you in advance. Below is my code. Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView mysonglistview;
String[] items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mysonglistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songlistview);
    runtimepermission();



}

public void runtimepermission(){

    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    display();

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();

                }
            }).check();

}

public ArrayList<File> findSong(File file){
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for (File singleFile: files){
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){

            arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
        }
        else {
            if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") ||
            singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){

                arrayList.add(singleFile);


            }
        }


    }

    return arrayList;

}

void display(){
    final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    items = new String[mySongs.size()];
    for (int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++){

        items [i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".wav","");

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    mysonglistview.setAdapter(myadapter);

    mysonglistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {

            String SongName = mysonglistview.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("songs", mySongs).putExtra("songname", SongName)
                    .putExtra("pos", 1));

        }
    });
}
```

}

Here are PlayerActivity.Java code

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_next, previous, pause;
TextView songTextlabel;
SeekBar songseekbar;

static MediaPlayer mymediaplayer;
int position;
String sname;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
Thread updateseekbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);

    songTextlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songlabel);
    songseekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Now Playing");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    updateseekbar = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int totalDuration = mymediaplayer.getDuration();
            int currentposition = 0;

            while (currentposition < totalDuration) {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    currentposition = mymediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    songseekbar.setProgress(currentposition);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    if (mymediaplayer != null) {
        mymediaplayer.stop();
        mymediaplayer.release();
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

    mySongs = (ArrayList) bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
    sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();

    String songName = i.getStringExtra("songname");

    songTextlabel.setText(songName);
    songTextlabel.setSelected(true);

    position = bundle.getInt("pos", 0);

    Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

    mymediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);

    mymediaplayer.start();
    songseekbar.setMax(mymediaplayer.getDuration());

    //seekbar color

    updateseekbar.start();
    songseekbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    songseekbar.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


    songseekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            mymediaplayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());

        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            songseekbar.setMax(mymediaplayer.getDuration());
            if (mymediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                mymediaplayer.pause();
            } else {
                pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                mymediaplayer.start();
            }

        }
    });

    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mymediaplayer.stop();
            mymediaplayer.release();
            position = ((position + 1) % mySongs.size());

            Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

            mymediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);

            sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();
            songTextlabel.setText(sname);

            mymediaplayer.start();
        }
    });

    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mymediaplayer.stop();
            mymediaplayer.release();
            position = ((position - 1) < 0) ? (mySongs.size() - 1) : (position - 1);

            Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mymediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);

            sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();
            songTextlabel.setText(sname);

            mymediaplayer.start();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're passing hardcoded param here

> ```
>         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class)
>                 .putExtra("songs", mySongs).putExtra("songname", SongName)
>                 .putExtra("pos", 1)); // change 1 to i
> ```

And in PlayerActivity:

At the top of class you declare you variable **position**

> int position;

By this time, you only declared int **position** ( default value for declared int is 0 )

Later on in the code you do this:

> sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();

**position** is still **0** at this point because it was only declared ( reason why you always get first song ).

After that you change the value of **position** to whatever it was passed through intent

> position = bundle.getInt("pos", 0);

To get what you wanted, you have to do

> position = bundle.getInt("pos", 0)
>
> sname = mySongs.get(position).getName().toString();

And that's it!

Reference for default values:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

On the side note, don't pass big objects through intent. You should use intents to only pass things like ID and then use that ID in receiving activity to fetch whatever you need.

**Edit:** Try and format your code nicely, it should yield you more responses in future.

Comment: Hello sir, i update  PlayerActivity. code . Can you please see it . Thank You

Comment: I found the problem, I will edit origin answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: Ok I edited my original answer, see if you can make it work. Let me know if I should clarify it further.

Comment: Ok I edited it once again for clarity, let me know how it goes!